# How does the "compressed form" of `cv::convertMaps` work?

Tags: opencv, interpolation

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga9156732fa8f01be9ebd1a194f2728b7f) for `convertMaps`  says that it supports the following transformation:

> `(CV_32FC1, CV_32FC1)→(CV_16SC2, CV_16UC1)` This is the most frequently used conversion operation, in which the original floating-point maps (see `remap`) are converted to a more compact and much faster fixed-point representation. The first output array contains the rounded coordinates and the second array (created only when `nninterpolation=false`) contains indices in the interpolation tables.

I understand that `(CV_32FC1, CV_32FC1)` is encoding `(x, y)` coordinates as floats. How does the fixed point format work? What is encoded in each 2-channel entry of the `CV_16SC2` matrix? What interpolation tables does the `CV_16UC1` matrix index into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going by what I remember from the last time I investigated this. Grain of salt and all that.

the fixed point format splits the integer and fractional parts of your (x,y)-coordinates into different maps.

it's "compact" in that `CV_32FC2` or 2x `CV_32FC1` uses 8 bytes per pixel, while `CV_16SC2 + CV_16UC1` uses 6 bytes per pixel. also it's integer-only, so using it can free up floating point compute resources for other work.

the integer parts go into the first map, which is 2-channel. no surprises there.

the fractional parts are converted to 5-bit integers, i.e. they're multiplied by 32. then they're packed together, lowest 5 bits from one coordinate, higher next 5 bits from the other one.

the resulting funny number has a range of `0 .. 1023`, or `0b00000_00000 .. 0b11111_11111`, which encodes fractional parts (0.0, 0.0) and (0.96875, 0.96875) respectively (that's 31/32).

during remap...

the integer map is used to look up, for every resulting pixel, several pixels in the source image required for interpolation.

the fractional map is taken as an index into an "interpolation table", which is internal to OpenCV. it contains whatever factors and shifts required to correctly blend the several sampled pixels into one resulting pixel, all using integer math. I guess there are multiple tables, one for each interpolation method (linear, cubic, ...).